# Facebook Catalogue - can't make multiple product variants per page work with JSON-LD

Tags: facebook, schema.org, microdata, json-ld, facebook-pixel

I'm struggling to get Facebook's micro data tag debugger to recognise more than one product variant defined in JSON-LD data, and formatted according to schema.org.

The problem is already described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268803/json-ld-microdata-for-a-product-with-multiple-variants-for-facebook-catalogs), but the only answers are from someone who has the same issue, and someone who pasted in the Facebook example data, which only contains 1 variant.

From trying to implement micro data tags to be picked up by Facebook to allow a catalogue to be updated, the consistent thing I've found is that the Google implementation finds the micro data tags wherever they are in the page, and whatever variation of schema.org product definitions they use, and the Facebook implementation fails for all but a very narrow set of scenarios.

Firstly, although not mentioned in the Facebook Developer help pages, it will only recognise JSON-LD data if it is within the HEAD tag. (It states that OpenGraph tags should be in the HEAD, but doesn't say this for JSON-LD.)  I've also found that it very rarely seems to be able to find the price data, and any validation failures are not explained very well.

I've tried formatting the JSON-LD data as follows:

- Include one Product object per variant
- Include one Product object with multiple ProductModel objects within it, one for each variant

Neither of these seems to work.

I've set up some test pages that can be used with the [Facebook micro data tag debugger](https://business.facebook.com/ads/microdata/debug):

- https://j0nkn1ght.github.io/fb-microdata1.html - This contains the exact data from the [Facebook developer help page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/guides/microdata-tags)
- https://j0nkn1ght.github.io/fb-microdata2.html - This contains 2 Products, one for each variant
- https://j0nkn1ght.github.io/fb-microdata3.html - This contains 1 Product, with 2 ProductModels, one for each variant

If you use the debugger to process these URLs, the first one successfully finds the product including the price, the second finds the first variant but ignores the second one, and the third can't find the price for the product.

Using the [Google Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) page successfully finds both variants for the last 2 URLs.

Has anyone successfully got Facebook to recognise more than one Product Variant on the same page?

As a bonus question, the other odd thing that I've found is that if I generate the JSON data from an ASP.Net MVC Core application, where it is injected into the page as part of the page render, the FB debugger always fails to find the price information, whereas if I take the rendered output and paste it into the view, the FB debugger finds the price information.  I've used Postman to verify that the rendered page is identical in both cases, down to white space, so I'm at a loss as to how to explain this.  Has anyone else experienced something similar?

Comment: It's FB rules. Google also enforces page-level requirements that are not defined in the schema.org data model. Neither Google nor FB agree to harvest data in the same way, irrespective of a standard data model. If you want a valid page, you have to carefully read the harvester's documentation.

Comment: I'd test via the real account over the debugger. I think Facebook gathers the SD via its pixel which probably behaves differently. And maybe the real code deals with SD things better. As you want auto catalog updates, maybe set up a test catalog and see if you can get it to update the multiple products.